# simple js source mapping

Tags: javascript, debugging, source-maps

I'm developing a tool that dynamically load javascript in the browser.

I want to allow users to debug generated code, but I also want to hide some of the generated line while debugging.

Example of the generated source:

```
define('simple','simple',function(module) {
   module.exports = function gogogo() {
      var a = require("./a");
      var b = require("./b");
      return a + b;
  };
});
```

Ideally, I want the first and last line to be hidden while debugging in devtools.
I know I could use source mapping, but I want to know if there is a simple way to just hide some line in debugger, or if there is some tool to generate a source map for this simple use case.

Comment: Were you able to get anywhere with this? I am facing a similar issue...

Comment: No, sorry. I revert to move the lines to hide very far on right; they are practically hidden, but is a little ugly.

Comment: Well, I found a simple solution for you: Take the function and `eval` it with `//@sourceURL` set, so you can trace the exact file name, line & column number inside your function, independent of the surrounding file.